# Subscribe messages for selected routing keys in single subscription (rabbitmq)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, messaging, stomp

How to subscribe messages for selected routing keys in single subscription. example:

User sending message described by "tags" (tags=routing keys):

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/example.tagA.tagB.tagC.tagD"), sending_message);
```

I want to subscribe messages for routing tagA OR tagB so it's working when I put 2 subscriptions:

```
socket.stomp.subscribe("/topic/example.#.tagA.#", notify());
socket.stomp.subscribe("/topic/example.#.tagB.#", notify());
```

Does it have some overhead(eg. network overhead) if there will be not 2 subscriptions but more eg. 50 ?
If previous solution have overhead is it possible to join this 2 subscriptions into one ? also solutions in single subscription looks better(because more concise).

Comment: Please, specify what library you are using to get precise answer.

Comment: hi, there are on the client javascript sockjs+stomp lib and on the backend java spring mvc. I'm using websockets(through sockjs+stomp) in spring4.

Comment: So, each web page is connected directly to RabbitMQ (through stomp )! is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure about technical implementation. I think that is'nt direcet connection from javascript client to rabbitmq and there is spring middleware.